# Generate a Rails model from within code (invoke generator from a controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a particular need to be able to invoke a Rails command from within code (ie when some action occurs). I need a model to be created with specific fields (which will be determined by a form) and run the created migration in the end.

So this form I have would create all the fields, which then would result with the creation of a model with its certain fields (table and columns)

So, is there a way to invoke `rails generate model NAME [field[:type][:index] field[:type]` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` from within a controller/ruby code?

Comment: Why do you have this need? I ask because it sounds quite problematic, and perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Well yes, maybe my solution is a bit too extreme. What I need to achieve is this: Create multiple categories with their own designated information fields (ie. Cars have different fields from Pets) and once such a category is created, the commands I need will be invoked and a new table for each category will be made. I know I could store all fields as some sort of string and then process it to display it properly, but I need a advanced search function for my web app and creating separate tables for each category seems the best way to achieve it. I would really like to hear alternatives for this

Comment: I would definitely pursue another solution – there are many potential ones depending on your needs – perhaps Rails `serialize`, or Postgres hstore, or a separate table like `category_fields`. Generating models and migrations in production seems like a world of hurt. I would suggest posting another question stating the problem you're trying to solve and the constraints (with more details about your search needs, for example) and I'm sure a lot of people will have good ideas.

Comment: I asked another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342851/how-to-handle-creating-categories-with-different-fields-for-each-of-them-in-rail ... The thing is that the categories would be created in the administration and this feature would be used with a lot of caution. I would appreciate your input on my newly created question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having one table per category, here's a more relational-database-y approach:

```
create table category (
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null
);

create table attribute (
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null
);

create table item (
    id serial primary key,
    category_id integer not null references category (id),
    description text
);

create table category_attribute (
    attribute_id integer not null references attribute (id),
    category_id integer not null references category (id)
);

create table item_attribute (
    attribute_id integer not null references (attribute.id),
    item_id integer not null references item (id),
    value text
);
```

When you create a category, you store its name (and any other one-to-one attributes) in the `category` table. You make sure the `attribute` table has an entry for every attribute the category has, and then use the `category_attribute` table to link those attributes to that category.

When you add a new member of a category, you use the `item` table to store the main things about the item and the `item_attribute` table to store the values of each of its attributes. So with the cars and pets approach you mentioned, your database might look like

```
category
 id | name
----+------
  1 | car
  2 | pet

attribute
 id |    name
----+------------
  1 | make
  2 | breed
  3 | model_year
  4 | name

category_attribute
 attribute_id | category_id
--------------+-------------
            1 |           1
            2 |           2
            3 |           1
            4 |           2

item
 id | category_id |  description
----+-------------+----------------
  1 |           1 | Hyundai Accent
  2 |           2 | Fuzzy kitty

item_attribute
 attribute_id | item_id |  value
--------------+---------+---------
            1 |       1 | Hyundai
            3 |       1 | 2007
            2 |       2 | DSH
            4 |       2 | Sam
```

This approach can feel pretty non-obvious, because it doesn't match the "one object with many attributes" style you use with Rails models. This is how relational databases work, however. I believe there's some ActiveRecord magic you can do to make the object/relational translation a little more automatic, but I don't remember what it's called at the moment.

Comment: I like this approach, however I am unsure how to achieve this in Rails.

Comment: Well, you could start by making those tables and models and do the linkages manually in helper methods on the models. Once you have a working thing, brush up on the association methods available in ActiveRecord to clean it up and make it nice.